# Добавление разных шаблонов страниц в визуальный редактор Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Кто знает как добавить разные страницы не только главную для такого визуального редактирования в Wordpress[image: Панель настройки страницы]

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду? Добавить другую страницу в меню кастойзера слева, по аналогии с "Настройки главной страницы"?

Comment: я имею ввиду чтобы у других страниц тоже была возможность выводить такой кастомайзер. Может у кого то есть ссылка на документацию где это описано

Comment: на данный момент такие настройки выводит только моя главная страница

Answer (score 0):

[Настройка кастомайзера в Wordpress](http://oddstyle.ru/wordpress-2/stati-wordpress/rukovodstvo-po-nastrojshhiku-kastomajzeru-tem-wordpress-chast-1.html)